# sudo apt-get install iotedge fails on raspberry pi

Tags: raspbian-jessie, apt

I am following this tutorial:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-install-iot-edge-linux

I am installing it on a clean raspberry PI with the following version:

Distributor ID: Raspbian
Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 8.0 (jessie)
Release:        8.0
Codename:       jessie

When I try to do sudo apt-get install iotedge

I have the following error

```
xx@xx:/etc/apt $  sudo apt-get install iotedge
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 iotedge : Depends: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0) but it is not installable
           Depends: libiothsm-std (= 1.0.9.4-1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any idea what am I missing?

Comment: Instructions are for Stretch. You're running Jessie. How do you know that's supposed to work?

Comment: I dont know, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

You are using **Raspbian Jessie**. This is unsupported since 2020-01-01 and its repositories are archived. You should use the current stable [Raspberry Pi OS Buster](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspberry-pi-os/).

If you really need to use **Jessie** then first you should look how to address its archived repositories and configure them in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

Comment: according to the documentation in IoT Edge, I should use stretch, but it seems also old, is Buster a new version of stretch?or should I stick to Stretch only?

Comment: @LuisValencia Buster is the stable generation of the Debian/RaspiOS distribution. Have a look at the [Current Releases](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianReleases#Current_Releases.2FRepositories). It is always a good idea to use the stable version.